# Creating site template with all custom lists and web parts from existing subsite

Tags: site-template, sub-site

I have a subsite from which I want to create site template with all custom lists and custom web parts on it. And I want to enable my end-users to create a new subsite from this template with a few clicks without creating any custom web parts and lists, all this web parts and lists will be included in template, so they can just choose this type of site. Main reason for this is because on existing subsite I have some web parts which include some JavaScript code in background.

Answer (score 3):

If it is team site (= not publishing site) you can go to Site Settings, and Save site as template and select to save all data on the site. Then you can create new sites based on that site that contains most of the customizations, but not permissions.

Comment: If it's a publishing site, then deactivate the publishing feature at the SPWEB level only and then you will get the SAVE AS TEMPLATE in the site settings