# How to upload the site template in SharePoint 2013 sub site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, site-template

I need to upload a site template in a subsite, and I need a clarification about whether site template covers the web parts also or not? I referred this link `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033.aspx` but I need more clarification about the same?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have gone through the link and you know what the link is all about.

I am just trying to add some couple of points into it. If you save your site as template with including content then it will also contains all the lists and custom WebParts.

But if your site is publishing site or you have activated the publishing site feature then you need to deactivate this feature first and then try the same.

It will back up all your **`Lists and WebParts`**

Please refer this [answer and comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/181436/30145)  for more detail.

Comment: cool, that's fine how can we upload that site template into the subsite?@TrimantraSoftwareSolution

Comment: have you gone through https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371B0F-00E0-4C49-A844-34759EBDD989 ??